# asp.net web api 2 identity performance

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Can we tune the performance of default asp.net web api 2 identity provider.

If I am not using the roles or claims, can I exclude them from the query generated by the identity provider. This may help improve the performance a lot.

I am referring to the class ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs created by the default web api project.

The steps that it follows is:

```
var user1 = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
                if (user1 == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user is not registered.");
                    return;
                }
```

**//Query gets executed once here**

```
        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }
```

**// Query gets executed once again here**

```
ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
             OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

**//This one generates one more query**

```
ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

**//Fires the same query as above**

```
AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
```

---

> THE WHOLE PROCESS TAKES 4 SECONDS. AM I DOING ANYTHING WRONG HERE? 
>   Can we eliminate some process / merge few of them and optimize the
>   same.

---

Thanks

Comment: What evidence do you have that empty roles/claims tables are causing performance issues?

Comment: The query is long and includes all those tables not needed in the query

Comment: Long query does not mean it is expensive to run. And the empty tables will not have any effect on the query performance. Have you checked the execution plain in SQL?

Comment: As I said, empty tables should not cause any performance issue. I suggest you run a profiler and find out what exactly is causing an issue. How many users do you have in your db?

Comment: That does not sound a lot. What is profiler saying about the missing time? What takes the most time?

Comment: Checked all the methods. ApplicationUser user = userManager.Find(context.UserName, context.Password); is taking the most of the time. This itself takes appx 4 seconds .

Answer (score 0):

We sort of have the same setup.

Does it happen on every single request?

We've had quite alot of problems with entity framework cold queries and view generation, however, the "second" query always goes really fast.

If that is the case you can try using ADO.net with Identity instead and pregenerate views for entity framework. However, it's still a messy solution and something I really think MS should adress.

[The article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx) is still very relevant regarding identity, and there by entity framework, "warm-up".